# character set and collation isn't supported on current database. "Legacy Character set" and "Legacy Collation" will be replaced with default values

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to update my WP website and all of a sudden I am getting this error.

*character set and collation isn't supported on current database. "Legacy Character set" and "Legacy Collation" will be replaced with default values.*

I have zero idea why this has randomly started happening, and quite frankly after google searching and only finding 2 results that don't help me I had no choice but to ask here.

I have tried changing the collation on my local mysql to the same as my production mysql, but not luck.

Comment: which databses do you actually have and which character sets maybe a change to utf8mb4 with utf8mb4 unicode ci  but make always a backup of then server